# Is it bad practice to perform http requests in main module?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to sync data from an external resource (file, server etc) into my DB every time the server starts.

**app.js**

```
const app = express();
app.use('/add', require('./addLayer'));

...

(async() => {
    const external_resource = await axios.get('...'); // get data 
    await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/add', external_resource.data); // add it to db
});
```

**addLayer.js**

```
const DBObject = require('../../models/DBObject')
const addNewLayer = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = validateData(req.body)
        await DBObject.create(data)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).send(err)
    }
}
```

I do not want to re-write the code in the `/add` route (which includes data validations), but I find performing POST requests in here not good for some reason. Is there a better way to do so?

Comment: What does that mean `good for some reason` some ? 
Using another file to handle the post request will be more structured way, this will increase the readability and re-useness.

Comment: I honestly don't know, for me (not a core-team nodejs developer) it seemed a little weird that every time the server starts it needs to execute a post request. I assume that a better way is what you suggested.

Comment: Yeah @rolory, go on. Let me know if you're still stuck at any point. Happy to help :)